# Wpf Addin's View cover other user control

Tags: c#, wpf, view, mahapps.metro, maf

I cover the Backtun Shell Project step by step.

[Hosting WPF Child Windows in Another Process](https://www.ikriv.com/dev/wpf/BaktunShell/)

But when the **View** show in the wpf shell, it cover other usercontrol.
Do not work when I set pannel.Zindex = 0.

Create view code:

```
    // must execute on UI thread
    public void CreateView()
    {
        View = FrameworkElementAdapters.ContractToViewAdapter(_remoteProcess.RemotePlugin.Contract);
    }
```

[Before load addIn View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3h9p.png)

[after load addIn View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPvAS.png)

[wpf live tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZQ3v.png)

thanks in advance

Comment: Hosting UI in another process is a bit extreme.  Have you considered sandboxing via `AppDomain`s?  It covers all the pros mentioned in that link

Comment: @MickyD yes  i had considered. But the scene I need is mixing x86|x64 dll